# GetProcessesByName isn't working

Tags: c#

After searching alot regarding this issue, I'm still facing problems in checking whether the running process has finished or not. 
When the user hit the 'Go' button in the GUI, the program is running for about 5 seconds and closes. When it is finished, I want to do something (e.g., green mark in GUI).

My problem is the 'GetProcessesByName' apparently cannot see the program, which is strange, because I see it in the task manager. The program name is `quartus_pgm.exe`. See the following code, I've tried `quartus_pgm`, or `quartus_pgm.exe`, or `quartus_pgm.exe32`(as seen in the task manager) but nothing!

If I put 'cmd' it does see it (the quartus_pgm is envoked from the cmd), but it is not what i'm looking for.
I've tried various methods:

```
Process[] targetProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(processName));
```

or this one:

```
 Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("quartus_pgm");
                      if (processes.Length > 0)
                        // do something;
```

or this one:

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("quartus_pgm.exe"))
                {
                    // do something;
                }
```

Comment: What's your machine configuration? What's your account privilege and quartus_pgm.exe's execution account's privilege?

Comment: Try to run your exe with admin rights.

Comment: Check the user under which it's running. If it's not your local user, you need to have admin rights to see it. Also, how do you start the process?

Comment: Do you create the process yourself? If so, why not use members of the `Process` class to wait for the process to finish?

Comment: Ok, thx all for your remarks! I've tried with exe, didn't matter. I'm working from work, so I'm not admin. Regarding the user it is running from - it is my user. what do u mean by machine configuration? it's window 7, 64 bits. the quartus_pgm is a command line executable command line, used to burn FPGA

Comment: I mean: Do you start `quartus_pgm` from your application using the `Process` class? Couldn't you use the respective `Process` instance to monitor whether the process has ended?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try remove `.exe` part.

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("quartus_pgm"))
{
         // do something;
}
```

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

> The process name is a friendly name for the process, such as Outlook,
>   that does not include the .exe extension or the path

**UPDATE**

Try to list all of process in your machine, look for the `quartus_pgm` process name.

```
 foreach (var process in Process.GetProcesses())
 {
     Console.WriteLine(process.ProcessName);
 }
```

Comment: then why this `Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("quartus_pgm");` didn't worked for roy.me?

Comment: @SidM: Are you can execute `quartus_pgm` in command line (CMD) ?

Comment: I tried it all, believe me... nothing works, and I do see it in the task manager.

Comment: @IswantoSan: I'm sending D:\altera\13.1\quartus\bin\quartus_pgm to CMD.exe with various paramters. I can see the 'quartus_pgm' in the task manager, under my user name, written in this form: 'quartus_pgm.exe *32', but if I try writing processes.Length, it always stays on 0.

Comment: @IswantoSan: however you are just printing the process name, this doesn't solve the problem and neither provides a solution to the question :(

Comment: @SidM: Yes, it's just print the process name, what is the process name for quartus_pgm?

Comment: Ok, @SidM! I've found the problem. It seems that if I'm envoking the quartus_pgm.exe from the cmd.exe, it isn't showed in the process list in the console, whereas if I envoke it without the cmd.exe, it does show. My problem now is I need to call the quartus_pgm.exe with parameters FROM the cmd.exe (it is a feature of the quartus_pgm.exe, calling it with filename, etc.). How can I do it without the cmd.exe?

Comment: Use `Process.Start()`. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Any chance that this method is case sensitive? If you loop through the processes, do you find it?

```
foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if (p.ProcessName.ToLower() == "quartus_pgm")
                {

                }
            }
```

Comment: the toLower is very important

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already starting the process yourself, why not just keep the `Process` reference to it? Then you can just do

```
if (process.HasExited) { ... }
```

(don't forget you have to call `process.Refresh` to make sure the `HasExited` property is updated properly)

Or even just wait on it's wait handle (ideally using asynchronous code).